# Which labels were used during a time period in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

Say I have three labels **work**, **personal**, **soccer** and I have for a period of time sent emails and labeled some of the conversations.

How would I see what labels were used during that period? I choose January 2012 and get a list of labels in use, e.g. **work**, **soccer**.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

[Graph Your Inbox](http://www.graphyourinbox.com/) will do this (although it is a Chrome extension, so you have to be using Chrome). After you install it, you just need to search for `label:thelabelyouareinterestedin`.